# Trying to get working wallectconnect/web3modal on safari/ios

Tags: web3js, bsc, walletconnect

I'm trying to get a React site work with web3modal and walletconnect.

When in a Metamask browser, my dapp on BSC works, but on Safari (MacOs and iOS), I show the web3modal, user gives permissions to TrustWallet (for example), but returning back to Safari, site doesn't get accounts and nothing works.

This is my code:

```
const providerOptions = {
    walletconnect: {
    package: WalletConnectProvider,
    options: {
        rpc: {
            56: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
            }
        },
        network: 'binance'
    }
 };
const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
    cacheProvider: true, 
    providerOptions 
});

const provider = await web3Modal.connect();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

At this point, when I try to get the accounts with:

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

I get:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Failed to get accounts
```

And in the console, a lot of calls to infura, what I cannot understand, why I need infura if using BSC (or the next question: how the f configure infura for this)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [Moralis](https://moralis.io/). It has SDK for React with cool hooks. It also supports different providers (walletconnect, metamask, ...). Take a look at [Moralis React Github](https://github.com/MoralisWeb3/react-moralis). It has own speedy nodes for BSC, ETH and Matic networks.

Example of getting user wallet address:

```
import React from "react";
import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis";

function App() {
  const { authenticate, isAuthenticated, user } = useMoralis();

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => authenticate()}>Authenticate</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome {user.attributes.ethAddress}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```